# php error message does not display on blank field

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form where a user is required to enter their full name, contact number and best time to call details. I would like to validate these fields on my web form so that users cannot submit the form without those fields being filled. I have used `if(empty($...))` and echoed my error message however, when i try to submit the blank form it doesn't display any of the error messages. How could i resolve this?

**CODE**

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/bootstrap.php');
    include("config/cn.php");

    $template['template'] = "page";
    if($_POST)
    {
        // Data pulled from input form
        $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
        if (empty($_POST['full_name']))
        {
            // Set error and return to form
            echo "Field cannot be left blank";
            header('Location: /call-back-form.php');
            exit;
        }

        $contact_number = $_POST['contact_number'];
        if (empty($_POST['contact_number']))
        {    
            // Set error and return to form
            echo "Field cannot be left blank";
            header('Location: /call-back-form.php');
            exit;    
        }

        $best_time_to_call = $_POST['best_time_to_call'];
        if (empty($_POST['best_time_to_call']))
        {
            // Set error and return to form
            echo "Field cannot be left blank";
            header('Location: /call-back-form.php');
            exit;
        }

        $enter_sql = "INSERT INTO contact (full_name, contact_number, best_time_to_call) 
            VALUES('$full_name' , '$contact_number' , '$best_time_to_call')";
        /*print($enter_sql);*/

        $enter_query = mysql_query($enter_sql) or die(mysql_error());
        header('Location: /thankyou.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Anything you `echo` before calling `header()` will be lost, and to be honest you shouldn't `echo` anything on the document before `header()` as it will throw errors of `headers already being passed`

Comment: You can't prevent a form from being submitted with a back-end language.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is an error in logic. You are doing an `echo` then `header`. Which means it shows the message and returns them to the previous page faster than they can see the message. Is this really what you wanted to do?

You should probably either post the form to itself and just just `echo` without the `header` where you want the errors displayed, or implement javascript form validation.

Also, you could use

```
<?
  header('Location: /call-back-form.php?message=Error');
?>
```

And then in call-back-form.php user

```
<?
  echo $_GET['message'];
?>
```

where needed

Comment: I understand, thanks. Is there a way where the error messages can be displayed on the same page as opposed to displaying it on a different page?

Comment: Well yes, my code example does just that. Detects the error and then redirects to the form with `message` parameter. On the form you just echo it where you need it.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but the echo will go in the if statement? and where do i put the header?

Comment: Header you leave where it is. Just add the ?message parameter, and remove the echo. Basically whatever you would `echo` add it as `?message=...` instead in the header.

Comment: Oh ok, is there any way of displaying it somewhere outside the textboxes so that it is more visible to the user?

Comment: I never said you need to display it in the textboxes. When you get returned because of error, you will be returned to `call-back-form.php?message=Something`. Then in call-back-form.php you can do `echo $_GET['message'];` anywhere you want it displayed.